# How update variable on click on yandex maps

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, yandex-maps

I want update variable when I click first time on yandex map.But it is not working. Handler of click on map is called definitely, but variable value is not updating.
Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgdq67to/3/). When I click on map I want update `filter.step` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change anything inside non angular components it won't run `$digest` to make effect of changes to everywhere it linked.

You need to apply changes for non angular components.

Try **[`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)**

Like this

```
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.filter.step = 2;
  })
```

<kbd>`DEMO`</kbd>